# Bootstrap config.json: edit and compile in PhpStorm

Tags: json, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, configuration, phpstorm

I have created a `config.json` file from an [online service](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/).

What I need to do is edit and compile **js, css** files with ***PhpStorm*** software. I have installed Gulp, nodejs, npm and other plugins but I don't know how to work with it.

Comment: do you need to compile bootstrap sources? You need to follow instructions from https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/getting-started/#grunt then. Grunt can be run in PhpStorm using [Grunt](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2018.1/grunt-tool-window.html) toolwindow

Comment: @lena yes I need to change for example default primary btn color and compile bootstrap css and js file. will `grunt` do it for me?

Comment: yes, it should - if you set up everything properly. please ead bootstrap docs